# How can size of the root disk in Google Compute Engine be decreased?

Tags: cloud, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

The root disk size in GCE is 25 gigs. How do I decrease this? I can't find the option in the console or the gcutil flags.

When I try to resize the persistent disk in the Google Cloud Platform Console: I get an error message that "Disk size must be between 25 GB and 65536 GB."

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can't reduce the disk size in the Compute Engine. After creating a disk you can only increase the size of the disk up to 65536 GB.

Even if you create a snapshot of the disk and create a new disk out of it, you can't set the size of the new disk to be below the snapshot's size.

One possible solution is, you can create a new disk with a smaller size and copy the files from the first disk to this one through cloud storage or other file transfer methods.

Answer (score 0):

We do not currently provide a way to shrink a disk volume after it has been increased. This would have to be done manually via copying the files.